# Add Author in say Command

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to add in my command say the author of the message. Something Like That:
**Hello World - @Author**
I tried to do this alone but I failed I hope you can help me.)
I don't really understand why it wouldn't work, I tried to change a lot but it still gives me the message without the Author

**My Current Code:**

```
const Command = require('../structures/command.js');
const SubCommand = require('../structures/subcommand.js');

module.exports = class Say extends Command {

  constructor(client) {
    super(client);
    this.name = "say";
    this.subcommands = [new EmbedSay(client, this)];
  }

  run(message, args, commandLang, databases, lang) {
    if (message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
      message.channel.send(args.join(' '));
      message.delete();
    } else {
      var embed = this.client.getg1cuEmbed(message);
      embed.setDescription(lang.missing_manageguild_permission);
      embed.setColor(this.client.config.colors.error);
      message.channel.send(embed);
    }
  }

}

class EmbedSay extends SubCommand {
  constructor(client, parentCommand) {
    super(client, parentCommand);

    this.name    = "embed";
    this.aliases = ["--embed"];
  }

  run(message, args, commandLang, databases, lang) {
    if (message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
      try {
        var json = JSON.parse(args.join(' '));
      } catch (e) {
        var embed = this.client.getg1cuEmbed(message);
        embed.setColor(this.client.config.colors.error);
        embed.setTitle(commandLang.json_error_title);
        embed.setDescription(commandLang.json_error_desc);
        message.channel.send(embed);
        return;
        
      }
      message.delete();
      if (json.content) {
        message.channel.send(json.content, json);
      } else {
        message.channel.send(json);
      }
    } else {
      var embed = this.client.getg1cuEmbed(message);
      embed.setDescription(lang.missing_manageguild_permission);
      embed.setColor(this.client.config.colors.error);
      message.channel.send(embed);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can ping the author like this: `\`Hello World - <@${message.author.id}>\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To gain the author of a message in discord.js simply:
To gain ID: `message.author.id`
To gain tag: `message.author.tag`
To gain a url: `message.author` **or**  `'<@!' + message.author.id + '>'`

Answer (score -1):

i am not really a fan of discord.js but i do know one thing, `user.mention` always works and it mentions the user who typed in the command. `member.mention` could also work as well.

If that doesn't work then I'm sorry for leading you off track, but maybe this will help: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome